# Generate Piecewise ParametricPlot from Graphics

Tags: graphics, parametric-functions

Some `Graphics` in *Mathematica* could also be described by functions, in particular by `ParametricPlot`s. For example, take this figure of a 'house' with a round 'roof'.

```
Graphics[{
    Line[{{-1,0},{-1,-1},{1,-1},{1,0}}],
    Circle[{0,0},1,{0,Pi}]
}]
```

[image: Simple Graphics]

Turning this manually into parametric functions gives:

```
Manipulate[
    ParametricPlot[
        Piecewise[{
            {{-1,-(tt-0)},0<=tt<1},
            {{-1+2(tt-1),-1},1<=tt<2},
            {{1,-1+(tt-2)},2<=tt<3},
            {{Cos[Pi(tt-3)],Sin[Pi(tt-3)]},3<=tt<4}
        }],
    {tt,0,t},Axes->False],
{{t,4},0,4}]
```

[image: Moving ParametricPlot]

Is it possible to *generate* a (possibly `Piecewise`) parametric function which may be drawn using `ParametricPlot` automatically based on `Graphics` as input?

Background: imagine using *Mathematica* to export [G-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code) for [CNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_control) laser [engraving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_engraving) or [cutting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cutting) while giving you control over the order, direction and speed of each segment, and allowing you to verify the behaviour of your CNC before printing. Note that exporting an SVG will not give you control over direction nor speed.

Comment: Per the GIF, you can export it with `"AnimationRepetitions"->Infinity` as an option and it'll repeat indefinitely.

Comment: Going to https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbMbE.gif shows me a GIF which loops indefinitely. As does the GIF I created locally. I think it's a browser thing. Though I could be wrong. Can't be bothered generating it again ;) thanks though.

Comment: the imgur one only loops twice. That’s Mathematica’s default.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Thanks! Any idea how to generate GIFs which only run Forward, and then return to the start?

Comment: Try `Export[..., Manipulate[..., AnimationDirection -> Forward], "AnimationRepetitions"->Infinity]`

Comment: That doesn't work, but `Export["figure.gif",ListAnimate[Replace[myFigure,head_[args__]:>Table[args]]],"AnimationRepetitions"->Infinity]` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[toParametricLines]
toParametricLines[mcm_: .1][g_Graphics] := Module[{bsfs = 
    MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeGraphics[g, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> mcm}], 1] /. 
      Line -> (BSplineFunction[#, SplineDegree -> 1] &)}, 
  ParametricPlot[Through@bsfs@t, {t, 0, 1}]]
```

**Examples:**

```
g1 = Graphics[{Line[{{-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}}], Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}]}];
toParametricLines[][g1]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
g2 = Graphics[{RandomColor[], BezierCurve @ #} & /@ RandomReal[1, {10, 4, 2}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[toParametricLines[][g2], Axes -> False]
```

[image]

**Update:** For the case of a single closed curve, we can get a single `BSplineFunction` (as opposed to one function for each `Line` object returned by `MeshPrimitives[...]`) using

```
ClearAll[toParametricLines2]
toParametricLines2[mcm_: .1][g_Graphics] := Module[{bsf = 
     MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeGraphics[g, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> mcm}], 1] /. 

      l : {__Line} :> BSplineFunction[Join @@ l[[All, 1]], SplineDegree -> 1] }, 
    ParametricPlot[bsf@t, {t, 0, 1}]]

toParametricLines2[][g1]
```

> same as the first picture above

Comment: Presumably there is only one cutting tool, so there should only be one BSplineFunction.

Comment: @Carl, right; good point. To get a single  `BSplineFunction` for all the `Line` primitives returned  by `MeshPrimitives[...]`  we need an additional step to combine the coordinates in the correct order.

Comment: You're basically approximating the original Graphic with a set of points and then interpolating those points. Cool idea. And definitely appropriate for any CNC task, as long as the approximation-resolution is higher than the CNC machine's resolution.

Comment: Nonetheless, I would have hoped there was a more fundamental way to 'explode' a Graphic and adapt the internal Mathematica code to a parametric function. For example, a Line[{{a,b},{c,d}}] must refer to some internal plot-function which takes a,b,c,d as input arguments (I assume).

Comment: @LBogaardt, you can control the approximation resolution using the argument `mcm`.

Comment: Yes, I see that. Though this method remains an approximation. In practice, that's fine. However, a direct conversion to functions 'feels' more neat. I guess one can implement wrappers for each type of `Graphic` which takes the arguments of the `Graphic` and converts this to a parametric function (as I did manually above).

Comment: I now see `InputForm[ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, Pi}]]` yields a `Graphic` with a `Line` with many points, similar to your approximation. So to *Mathematica*, a `Plot` internally is a `Graphic` and a `Graphic` is *not* internally a `Plot`, as I first assumed (see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphics.html)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function which takes `Graphics` as input and outputs a `Piecewise` parametric function by replacing the `Head`. The list of implemented `Graphics` types can easily be extended.

```
graphicsToParametricFunctions::grphtp="Unknown graphics type: `1`";
graphicsToParametricFunctions=Function[{graphics},Module[{line=Function[{pointPairs,t},With[{len=Length[pointPairs]},Piecewise[MapIndexed[{{((#2[[1]]-len t))#1[[1,1]]+(1+len t-#2[[1]])#1[[2,1]],(#2[[1]]-len t)#1[[1,2]]+(1+len t-#2[[1]])#1[[2,2]]},(#2[[1]]-1)/len<t<#2[[1]]/len}&,pointPairs]]]]},Module[{rules={Line[args__/;Depth[args]==3]:>Function[{t},line[Subsequences[args,{2}],t]],Line[args__/;Depth[args]==4]:>Function[{t},line[Flatten[Map[Subsequences[#,{2}]&,args],1],t]],Circle[{centerx__,centery__},radius__,{arc1__,arc2__}]:>Function[{t},{centerx+radius Cos[(1-t) arc1+t arc2],centery+radius Sin[(1-t) arc1+t arc2]}],BezierCurve[args__]:>Function[{t},Map[BernsteinBasis[Length[args]-1,#,t]&,Range[0,Length[args]-1]].args]}},Function[{t},Evaluate[PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[MapIndexed[If[AnyTrue[Keys[rules],Function[{rule},MatchQ[#1,rule]]],{Replace[#1,rules][t-#2[[1]]+1],#2[[1]]-1<t<#2[[1]]},Message[graphicsToParametricFunctions::grphtp,#1]]&,Flatten[Level[graphics,1]]]]]]]]]];
```

**Case 1**

Two different types of `Graphics` which are attached, shaped as a house.

```
houseGraphic=Graphics[{Line[{{-1,0},{-1,-1},{1,-1},{1,0}}],Circle[{0,0},1,{0,Pi}]}]
```

[image: Graphic of a house]

```
houseParametricFunction = graphicsToParametricFunctions[houseGraphic]
```

[image: Piecewise of a house]

```
Manipulate[Show[ParametricPlot[houseParametricFunction[tt],{tt,0,t}],PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1}},ImageSize->220,Axes->False],{t,0,2,0.1}]
```

[image: GIF of a house]

**Case 2**

Two `Line`s which are separate.

```
twoLinesGraphic=Graphics[{Line[{{{-1,1},{-1,-1},{1,-1},{1,1},{-1,1}},{{-1/2,1/2},{-1/2,-1/2},{1/2,-1/2},{1/2,1/2},{-1/2,1/2}}}]}]
```

[image: Graphic of two squares]

```
twoLinesParametricFunction=graphicsToParametricFunctions[twoLinesGraphic]
```

[image: Piecewise of two squares]

```
Manipulate[Show[ParametricPlot[twoLinesParametricFunction[tt],{tt,0,t}],PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1}},ImageSize->220,Axes->False],{t,0,1,0.05}]
```

[image: GIF of two squares]

**Case 3**

Random `BezierCurve`s.

```
SeedRandom[1]
bezierGraphic=Graphics[Map[BezierCurve[#]&,RandomReal[1,{10,4,2}]]];
```

[image: Graphic of random Beziers]

```
bezierParametricFunction=graphicsToParametricFunctions[bezierGraphic]
```

[image: Piecewise of random Beziers]

```
Manipulate[Show[ParametricPlot[bezierParametricFunction[tt],{tt,0,t}],PlotRange->{{0,1},{0,1}},ImageSize->220,Axes->False],{t,0,10,0.5}]
```

[image: GIF of random Beziers]

**Case 4**

Not implemented `Graphics` type.

```
graphicsToParametricFunctions[Graphics[Disk[]]]
```

[image: Screenshot of an error]